# What’s this gundam?

Tags: character-identification, mobile-suit-gundam

Some time between 2005-2008, I watched a movie involving big gundam robots (my parents had a DVD if it, so it could be a good deal older). I do not recall much, I’m mainly going off a picture I drew at the time:

[image: masterpiece clue]

In the middle left is a red robot. I believe it was “discovered” first (in fact, I think in the first scene movie, some characters stumbled across it in like a cave or canyon or something). It looked a good deal like Optimus Prime if memory serves me right.

In the upper middle is a green robot with a red visor, and I think a red spiked mohawk (kind of like a dragon or stegosaurus, but restricted just to the head). It had a bazooka and shot its fist out at some moment. I believe it was evil, and came from space. It definitely blew up a city at some point.

Third, in the lower right is a white robot. I think it had a battle axe, and its head was noticeably rounder than the others. I don't remember much about it.

I think everything else was probably just creative liberties that are not relevant.

Comment: And how long have you been a professional artist?

Answer (score 3):

Your description of the third one, white with blue and yellow with a round head, made me think of [Turn A Gundam](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/System-%E2%88%8099_%E2%88%80_Gundam#Armaments) although it does not wield any sort of axe.

[image]

[PF-78-3A Gundam “Amazing Red Warrior”](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/PF-78-3A_Gundam_Amazing_Red_Warrior) Matches your description of a red Optimus Prime. However I have yet to find it in any video form.

[image]